# Scala: Two implicit manifiests

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

Say I have this function in a class:

```
  def serializeObject[O<:MongoModel, F<:FunnelJob](mongoObject:O):F = {
    grater[F].asObject(mongoObject)
  }
```

I will not be able to compile this because I need a manifest for O and F. But I am unable to actually use to implicit manifest calls

```
  def serializeObject[O<:MongoModel, F<:FunnelJob](mongoObject:O)(implicit mf:Manifest[O], implicit m:Manifest[F]):F = {
    grater[F].asObject(mongoObject)
  }
```

is invalid, for example. How can I have two generics with two manifests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `implicit` keyword, it applies to the entire parameter list in this context:

```
def serializeObject[O<:MongoModel, F<:FunnelJob](mongoObject:O)(implicit mf:Manifest[O], m:Manifest[F]):F
```

Side notes:

1. you probably don't need `Manifest[O]`;
2. when calling, you'll need to provide the type parameters explicitly or have a clear expected type, otherwise `F` will be inferred to `Nothing`;
3. `Manifest`s are semi-deprecated and should be replaced by `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` in most cases. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html.